# Add child nodes to a nested list dynamically (Sencha Touch 2)

Tags: nested-lists, sencha-touch-2

I wonder if you could help me with a problem. I have a nestedlist with 2 levels. When I tap an item on the third level, I dynamically want to query another store that appends itself as a 3rd lvl child node and let it appear.

This is an example of my nestedList. I actually also catch the id of the item I have tapped and send it to a non Sencha API but I didn't include it to the source.

```js
{    
    xtype: 'nestedlist',
    store: 'PackageGroupStore',
    listeners: {
        itemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, target, record){
            // add PackageProductStore here and make it visible
        }
}
```

I already found this one: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/nestedlist/

But from my understanding it only dynamically adds detailContainers.

Thanks for reading,
Marv

Comment: Just to let you know. I ended up using a detailCard after my leaf notes and set it up as list. Then again I used an itemtap function on this detailCard to access the "actual" detailCard.